# How to set default value for drop-down in react?

Tags: reactjs, select

Hi I am working on React Js drop-down. I want to set default value for the drop-down when first time page is rendered. Once user is select any value from drop-down then I am storing same value in redux store and setting same value for drop-down. Below is my code.

```
 render() {
  const {
   allOpenStoresSearchTerms,
    } = this.props;
    return (
     <SelectWithMargin
          instanceId="storeFilter"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={allOpenStoresSearchTerms.selectedOption}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Store Type"
          clearable={false}
     />
  }
}
```

Below is my handle event.

```
  handleChange(selectedOption) {
    this.props.searchParameters(
      this.state.searchValues,
      this.state.searchDbTarget,
      '',
      selectedOption
    );
    const openAllStores = {
      ...this.props.allOpenStoresSearchTerms,
      selectedOption,
    };
    this.props.setAllOpenStoresSearchTerms(openAllStores);
  }
```

Whenever I choose some value in dropdown, I am storing value in redux store and setting same value for drop down. Now I want to choose value when the page is loaded first time. Below are the values of drop-down.

```
 const options = [
  { value: 'true', label: 'Open Stores' },
  { value: 'false', label: 'All Stores' },
];
```

Can someone help me to set default value when the page is loaded? I am not sure where exactly we need to set default value? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: set `allOpenStoresSearchTerms.selectedOption` with a default value in redux `initialState` ?

Comment: May be i do not know. I want to set default value Open Stores when the page is loaded.

Comment: Set it in your `initlaState` `{ allOpenStoresSearchTerms: { selectedOption: { value='true', label: 'Open Stores'} } }`

Comment: It is working. Please post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the default values as `initialState`

```
const initialState = {
  allOpenStoresSearchTerms: {
    selectedOption: {
      value: 'true',
      label: 'Open Stores',
    },
  },
};

function reduer(state = initialState, action) {
  ...
}
```